# Alternative repo for RHEL 5.4

Tags: linux, php, redhat

Can anybody recommend a respectable alternative repo for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4? I want to get PHP 5.4 especially.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the faq.

Answer (score 1):

I like the IUS repository so far, they work quite well with the 5 series (CentOS in my case)

http://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

I second the IUS repo.  The only issue is if you are running other tools that depend on certain versions of PHP.  Due to the naming scheme used by IUS, this can create issues.

Also, don't forget the EPEL.

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

I find these two repos to be very reliable.

Comment: EPEL explicitly does not provide anything that replaces/conflicts with the base RHEL/CentOS/SL repositories.